# Is there something like the unix command "top" for CUDA?

Tags: linux, unix, gpu, resource-monitor

More generally, how can you check the current status of your GPU? (current number of threads running, memory state, and so on).

(I'm using linux, so Windows-only solutions, while interesting, won't solve my problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Nvidia, you could use the [**Visual Profiler**](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler) utility included in the [CUDA Toolkit](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) :

[image: image1]

For Radeon, perhaps the [ATI Tray Tools](http://www.guru3d.com/article/ati-tray-tools-/) can do the same (but I am not sure).

Comment: Pretty cool, and it seems to work on Linux, too! I'll probably award you the bounty, will just wait a bit more to see if other people have other solutions to offer.

Answer (score 0):

I use [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The screenshots don't show any computation monitoring capabilities... Does it really have them?